# sort matrix or data frame by a specific row

Tags: r

I want to sort a matrix or data frame by it's  second row. 
I find a way.

```
tt<-c(3,2,3,5,3,5,5,4,3,1,5,2,1,5,4,1,3,5,3,3)
ff<-matrix(tt,nrow=5)
gg<-t(ff)
nn<-gg[order(gg[,2],decreasing = T),]
ff<-t(nn)
ff
```

any alternative or suggestion?

Comment: As far as I know, `order` is the preferred method for such actions in base R. It can also be used to sort by multiple rows. If you are working with "gigantic" (> 1GB datasets), you may take a look at the `data.table` package and its `setkey` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to transpose the matrix in order to sort the matrix by second row. Specifying the order according to the second row at the column index should also work.

```
ff[,order(ff[2,], decreasing = T)]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    1    3    5
[2,]    5    3    2    2
[3,]    4    5    3    1
[4,]    3    3    5    5
[5,]    1    3    3    4
```

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. Seems to match with OP's expected result and is more straight-forward.

Comment: Thank you. my mistake was `ff[order(ff[2,], decreasing = T),]`

Comment: @thelatemail. I guess the question looks very normal and has very standard way to deal with. But it can also be people overlooked it. Sometimes, it is a little bit confusing between sorting rows independently and sorting by rows or sorting columns independently and sorting by columns which can all happen in matrix. But the only operation can happen in data frame is sorting by columns if you want to maintain the data.frame class still.